# Creating a new Bitmap with Pixel Data in JNI?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I've the below code to create a BitMap (Just a Black / Gray Image) in the JNI with 'ARGB_8888' configuration. But when I dump the content of the Bitmap in the Java code, I'm able to see only the configurations, but not the Pixel Data in the Bitmap.

JNI Code

```
// Image Details
int imgWidth = 128;
int imgHeight = 128;
int numPix = imgWidth * imgHeight;

// Creaing Bitmap Config Class
jclass bmpCfgCls = env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap$Config");
jmethodID bmpClsValueOfMid = env->GetStaticMethodID(bmpCfgCls, "valueOf", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;");
jobject jBmpCfg = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(bmpCfgCls, bmpClsValueOfMid, env->NewStringUTF("ARGB_8888"));

// Creating a Bitmap Class
jclass bmpCls = env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap");
jmethodID createBitmapMid = env->GetStaticMethodID(bmpCls, "createBitmap", "(IILandroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;");
jBmpObj = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(bmpCls, createBitmapMid, imgWidth, imgHeight, jBmpCfg);

// Creating Pixel Data
int triplicateLen = numPix * 4;
char *tripPixData = (char*)malloc(triplicateLen);
for (int lc = 0; lc < triplicateLen; lc++)
{ 
    // Gray / Black Image
    if (0 == (lc%4))
        tripPixData[lc] = 0x7F; // Alpha
    else
        tripPixData[lc] = 0x00; // RGB
}

// Setting Pixels in Bitmap
jByteArr = env->NewByteArray(triplicateLen);
env->SetByteArrayRegion(jByteArr, 0, triplicateLen, (jbyte*)tripPixData);
jmethodID setPixelsMid = env->GetMethodID(bmpCls, "setPixels", "([IIIIIII)V");
env->CallVoidMethod(jBmpObj, setPixelsMid, (jintArray)jByteArr, 0, imgWidth, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);

free(tripPixData);

// Return BitMap Object
return jBmpObj;
```

In JAVA (Output)

```
// Checking the Configuration / Image Details
jBmpObj.getWidth() - 128
jBmpObj.getHeight() - 128
jBmpObj.getRowBytes() - 512
jBmpObj.getConfig() - ARGB 8888

// Getting Pixel Data
imgPixs = new int[jBmpObj.getWidth() * jBmpObj.getHeight()];
jBmpObj.getPixels(imgPixs, 0, jBmpObj.getWidth(), 0, 0, jBmpObj.getWidth(), jBmpObj.getHeight());

// Running a Loop on the imgPixs
imgPixs[<0 - imgPixs.lenght>] - 0 (Every Pixel Data)
```

I used the same concept to create a Bitmap in the Java Code, and it works fine (Even I'm able to see the image). But I want the logic to be in the JNI part and not in Java Code. So I tried the above logic and it failed in setting the Pixel Data.

Any input in fixing this issue will be really helpful,..

Answer (score 10):

Full working example:

```
jclass bitmapConfig = jniEnv->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap$Config");
    jfieldID rgba8888FieldID = jniEnv->GetStaticFieldID(bitmapConfig, "ARGB_8888", "Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;");
    jobject rgba8888Obj = jniEnv->GetStaticObjectField(bitmapConfig, rgba8888FieldID);

    jclass bitmapClass = jniEnv->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap");
    jmethodID createBitmapMethodID = jniEnv->GetStaticMethodID(bitmapClass,"createBitmap", "(IILandroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;");
    jobject bitmapObj = jniEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(bitmapClass, createBitmapMethodID, _width, _height, rgba8888Obj);

    jintArray pixels = jniEnv->NewIntArray(_width * _height);
    for (int i = 0; i < _width * _height; i++)
    {
        unsigned char red = bitmap[i*4];
        unsigned char green = bitmap[i*4 + 1];
        unsigned char blue = bitmap[i*4 + 2];
        unsigned char alpha = bitmap[i*4 + 3];
        int currentPixel = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | (blue);
        jniEnv->SetIntArrayRegion(pixels, i, 1, &currentPixel);
    }

    jmethodID setPixelsMid = jniEnv->GetMethodID(bitmapClass, "setPixels", "([IIIIIII)V");
    jniEnv->CallVoidMethod(bitmapObj, setPixelsMid, pixels, 0, _width, 0, 0, _width, _height);
```

where bitmap is unsigned char*.

Comment: Thanks! thinks works great! do you know if allocating the memory in this way would count towards Native memory vs java Heap memory? (Im doing this to avoid OOM on lower end devices)

Comment: This code was really helpful for me. I translated it into Rust / JNI, but same basic idea! Not sure about the performance of continually getting it over and over, but I suggest people cache any results on the java side if any objects are the same (retrieving the same one again)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast byte[] to int[] in Java, therefore you cannot cast it in JNI. But you can cast char* to int*, so you can simply use your tripPixData to fill a new jjintArray.

Comment: I did try that, looks like it causes memory (scope) related issue. It says "(Address of tripPixData) is not a Valid JNI reference". If it is a casting Issue, I will give a try to create an int[] directly.

Comment: You cannot supply tripPixData as a parameter to setPixels method, you must create a Java array with `env->NewIntArray()`, and call `env->SetIntArrayRegion()`. What I tried to explain is that you can cast a `char* tripPixData` to `jint*` for this latter call.

Comment: I hope you understand that what you are doing is good for educational purposes only. To work with bitmaps efficiently from C, you should use [Android native Bitmap API](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/#bitmap).

Comment: Thanks for the info. env->NewIntArray() followed by env->SetIntArrayRegion() did work. But it saw one more issue here, if is set each pixel data to "0x7F", get pixel data print all the values to be "0x00". But if I set it to "0X7F000000" it prints the proper value. Don't know the reason, but this lead me to ask the actual question here..

Comment: Yes, the ARGB values in your bitmap pixels are arranged this way: A is the most significant byte, B is the least significant.

Answer (score 0):

```
IN Android each pixel represented as 0xFFFFFFFF ie ARGB.
0xFF referes most significamt 8 bits of given data.
From your snippet, where you are getting soure image data? But i have solved this issue
by using following code base.i hope this ll help you.
```

// Creating Pixel Data

```
unsigned char* rawData = //your raw data

**Note**: here you have get each r,g & b component as 8 bit data //If it is rgb image,if it             
is monochrome you can use raw data

int triplicateLen = imgheight * imgwidth;
int *tripPixData = (int*) malloc(triplicateLen * sizeof(int));

if(rgb){
       for (int lc = 0; lc < triplicateLen ; lc++){
            tripPixData [lc] = (0xFF << 24) | (r[lc] << 16) | (g[lc] << 8) | b[lc]; 
       }
 }else{
      for (int lc = 0; lc < triplicateLen ; lc++){
            tripPixData [lc] = (0xFF << 24) | (rawData [lc] << 16) | (rawData [lc] << 8) | rawData [lc];    
       }
 }
```